# How to integrate Low Search with Ajax?

Tags: low-search

I am at a loss on how to implement Ajax in Low Search.

There is currently no documentation on how to do Ajax with Low Search in the Low Search docs.

I already perused some answers in expressionengines stackexchange(second question one is mine)

http://expressionengine.stackexchange... 
http://expressionengine.stackexchange...

but the answers are very cryptic, don't show any low search forms and results tag examples and doesn't really help anyone new to implementing Low Search with Ajax.

Does someone have a step-by-step tutorial on how to use Low Search with Ajax?

Comment: See https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/no_idea_how_to_integrate_low_search_with_ajax#reply_11128411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a gist of the approach I mentioned in the GetSat thread: https://gist.github.com/4632695

That should give you a good starting point.